# Using pip in OSGeo4W64

Tags: osgeo4w, pip

I Successfully installed pip but when I ran pip it gave me the following error:

> C:\PYQGIS\DOCS>pip   File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site.py",
>   line 177
>       file=sys.stderr)
>           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

For using `pip` in OSGeo4W, run it at the *OSGeo4W Shell* (`C:\OSGeo4W64\OSGeo4W.bat`):

[image: pip]

Answer (score -1):

Already solved just use pip3 on python3+